# WebStorm not actually saving files?

Tags: webstorm

I'm not sure what setting I changed, but now when I save any file in WebStorm, the file doesn't actually get saved on the disk (which means my React server doesn't reload).

When I make a change, save it, open up Settings and then hit "OK", then the file saves -- I can see the "modified" date update in File Explorer, and the server refreshes.

I recently fiddled with System Settings > Synchronization (so that my server wouldn't reload basically any time I typed, only when I saved), and 
I think that may have caused the problem, but I've currently got it set to the first 3 options checked:

```
[X] Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation
[X] Save files on frame deactivation
[X] Save files automatically if application is idle for 15 sec
[ ] Use "safe write" (save changes to a temporary folder first)
```

Which I think was the state before I changed the settings. I don't think I changed anything else!

I also noticed that Settings > Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript had "Recompile on changes" unchecked so I rechecked that, no help.

Another change I made recently was that I added a line to my TSLint config for `no-string-literal-keys: false` or something, though that was in a different project than I'm currently testing.

The problem occurs in both projects.

Comment: 1) Do you have asterisk enabled for modified files (will be shown next to the file name in editor tab). If not -- enable it (use `asterisk` as keyword in search field of the Settings/Preferences window) and see if it will disappear when you hit Save. 2) How do you save -- a shortcut or a toolbar icon/menu item? If it's a shortcut, make sure that it triggers the actual `File | Save All` action; 3) If you use custom/3rd party plugins -- try updating them all first; if issue remains -- disable them all and see how it will behave then. That includes custom GUI themes as well.

Comment: That "Save All" thing did it. But that appears to be because Ctrl+S wasn't doing _anything_ before, because...there's no "Save" command? Very strange. But this appears to fix it.

Comment: There is no "Save" action -- it's "Save All" and default shortcut is `Ctrl+S`. If it had no action assigned .. or "Save All" had no shortcut .. then there must have been some glitch/issue with the settings. No clues why it may have happen (as I do not know what version you use there and other nuances) .. but I do remember seeing similar case some time ago (3- 5months ago or more). you got it working now, so it's all good.